# An isoperimetric inequality for curve in the plane?

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, inequalities

Let $f(x,y)=0$ be a (smooth) simple closed curve $C$ on the plane and $R$ the region bounded by $C$ (appropriately oriented). Assume the origin lies in the interior of $R$.

> **QUESTION.** Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Is this true?
>   $$\int_Cr\,ds\geq 2\cdot Area(R).$$
>   Equality iff $C$ is a circle centered at the origin.

Comment: If $C$ is regular enough (e.g. $C^1$) doesn't this this follow from the diveregence theorem applied to $(x,y)$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Good idea there.

Comment: Looking infinitesimally, $\frac12r\Delta s$ is not less than the area of a triangle with vertex at origin and side $\Delta s$. Such triangles cover $R$, thus the inequality. Equality takes place only if the radius-vector is always orthogonal to the tangent line, that means that the derivative of $r$ is zero.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I almost agree, but does this not matter whether the curve is convex or concave? In other words, is the inequality local or an average?

Comment: If R is convex and origin is inside (or even if it is star-shaped with respect to the origin), the triangles cover it  without overlaps. Otherwise overlaps are possible. But definitely any point p in R is covered by the segment 0s, where s is the point in which the continuation of the ray 0p meets the boundary of R.

Comment: It generalizes to $\int_{\partial U} r \ge n \operatorname{Vol} U$, for $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a bounded domain with $C^1$ boundary, with the origin in its interior, by the same proof as Piotr Hajlasz's. Maybe even with the origin on the boundary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Expanding on the comment of RBega2:

Let $(x(t),y(t))$, $t\in [0,1]$ be a parametrization of $C$. From [Green's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensTheorem.html), 
$$\int_C-y\,dx+x\,dy=\iint_R2\,dxdy=2\cdot Area(R).$$
From [Cauchy-Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality,
$$\vert\langle x,y\rangle\cdot\langle -\dot y,\dot x\rangle\vert
\leq \Vert\langle x,y\rangle\Vert\,\,\Vert\langle -\dot y,\dot x\rangle\Vert
=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)^{1/2}.$$
Therefore, we have
\begin{align*}
2\, Area(R)=
\int_Cx\, dy-y\, dx&=\int_0^1x(t)\dot y(t)-y(t)\dot x(t)\, dt \\
&\leq
\int_0^1(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)^{1/2}\, dt \\
&=\int_Cr\, ds.
\end{align*}
Equality holds if and only if $\langle x,y\rangle$ is parallel to $\langle\dot y,-\dot x\rangle$, that is if $\langle x,y\rangle$ is orthogonal to the velocity vector $\langle\dot x,\dot y\rangle$ which is exactly when $C$ is a circle centered at the origin.